# Array challenge

Tags: arrays, recursion

```
public class Testfor
{
    public static int ArrayChallenge(int[] arr)
    {
        int[] temp = new int[arr.length - 1];
        int diff = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++)
        {
            diff = Math.abs(arr[i] - arr[i + 1]);
            temp[i] = diff;
        }
        arr = temp;
        for (int i:arr)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        if (arr.length > 1)
        {
            ArrayChallenge(arr);
        }
        else
        {
            diff = arr[0];
            System.out.println("diff" + diff);
        }
        return diff;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // keep this function call here     
        //Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("answer:" + ArrayChallenge(new int[] { 5, 7, 16, 1, 2 }));
    }
}
```

Here the input is an array of integers finally the array should be reduced to the size of one element by finding the absolute difference between two elements.

I am using recursion to solve this but I am getting 1 as the answer can someone please someone help to solve it?

```
    input:[5,7,16,1,2]
    [2,9,15,1]
    [7,6,14]
    [1,8]
    [7]--->the array should reduce in the following manner to get an answer and finally should return the last element
    output:7
```

Comment: This would be easy in C# - `while (input.Length > 1) input = input.Skip(1).Zip(input, (i1, i0) => i1 > i0 ? i1 - i0 : i0 - i1).ToArray();`

Comment: This is happening because of the way recursion works. If you debug the program you would find out why it's returning 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just preserve the return value

```
public class Testfor
{
    public static int ArrayChallenge(int[] arr)
    {
        int[] temp = new int[arr.length - 1];
        int diff = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++)
        {
            diff = Math.abs(arr[i] - arr[i + 1]);
            temp[i] = diff;
        }
        arr = temp;
        for (int i:arr)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        if (arr.length > 1)
        {
            diff = ArrayChallenge(arr);
        }
        else
        {
            diff = arr[0];
            System.out.println("diff" + diff);
        }
        return diff;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // keep this function call here     
        //Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("answer:" + ArrayChallenge(new int[] { 5, 7, 16, 1, 2 }));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thnak you so much